# External VS Code Compiler

Tags: c++, c, linux, visual-studio-code

is there any way to connect an external compiler to VS Code?
I have a compiler delivered by the client which is located in a folder:

```
app\cc\linuxacu\x86_64-poky-mingw32\usr\bin\poky-linux-gnu
```

I would like to add it to VS Code to be able to compile the project directly in the editor. Is it possible to create a 'task' that will use the compiler from the specified path?
Additionally, I need to compile two types of files:

1. Makefile located under this path:

app\Makefile.mk

2. The C file that is currently open

app\src\device\type\src

I tried to create a task but unfortunately I can't run it properly.
Result:

> The terminal process failed to launch: Starting directory (cwd)
> "C:/Users/Kxk/app/Makefile.mk" does not exist.

```
{
    // See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=733558
    // for the documentation about the tasks.json format
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "label": "C/C++ LinuxARM Compiler Makefile",
            "type": "shell",
            "command": "C:/Users/Kxk/app/cc/linuxacu/x86_64-poky-mingw32/usr/bin/poky-linux-gnu/poky-linux-gnu-gcc",
            "args": [
                "-g"
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "C:/Users/Kxk/app/Makefile.mk",
                //"cwd": "${file}"
            },
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Any compilation in VS code is done by an external compiler, there is no other option. So you may want to ask a somewhat different question. Do you have a problem interpreting "Starting directory (cwd) "C:/Users/Kxk/app/Makefile.mk" does not exist."? Perhaps there is no such path, or there is a file that is not a directory?

Comment: did you save the compiler directory in OS directory?